# How do Oracle's skills combo with his other spells?

Tags: dota-2

I've tried to play the recently added Oracle hero. However I have a hard time understanding how his skills synergize together and how they synergize with spell from other heroes. Any tips would be very helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oracle is a bit hard to get at first sight but as you look closely to his skills, this hero proves to be very effective.

### How Oracle's skills synergize together and their utility

- Cast **Fate's Eddict** and **Purifying Flames** on an **ally or yourself** : Damage is blocked by Fate's Eddict so the target only gets healed.
- **Out of fights** you can heal an ally for up to 800HP with your skills only by using **False Promise, Fate's Eddict and Purifying Flames** : False Promise doubles all the heals from Purifying Flames and Fate's Eddict blocks the damage.
- Use **Purifying Flames to finish enemy** (instant nuke). if it fails you can **purge the heal** with Fortune's End.
- **Fate's Eddict + Ghost Scepter** makes you immune to both magic and physical damage (you can **still take pure damage** though). Same goes with an Etheral Blade (can be useful to save an ally even though you will rarely farm an Etheral Blade on Oracle)
- **False Promise** synergize very well **with** Dazzle's **Shallow Grave** : even if your ally took more damage than healing, he won't die when False Promise ends.
- Generally when an ally is under the **False Promise** buff you want to **use all your heals** immediatly (Mekansm/Urn) and spam Purifying Flames on them. Since the Heals is apply only at the end, it's not a waste to use them even if they are full life when you cast False Promise on them.
- Use **Fortune's End** to **remove positive buff on enemy** (Drums, Runes, Guardian Angel, whatever..)
- **Just before a fight/push :** use 2 instances of Purifying Flames' on your carry, guaranteeing him 2 instances of heal for the begining of the fight/push.
- **Purifying Flames cancels potions** (even on yourself)
- **Don't cast Fate's Eddict on your right clickers ally** (Slark, Lycan, Void, phantom Assassin etc.). The magic imunity is nice but they need to attack in order to do damage !

### Some tips/Infos to keep in mind

First and before anything, most of Oracle spells are spammable which makes this hero very active in fight (Like Skywrath Mage). It also makes the hero very mana intensive so Arcane Boots are almost always required as well as a mana regen item (Euls/Orchid/Urn).

Then :

- You can debuff Repel with Fortune's End.
- Linken's Sphere will block Fortune's End upon cast but not if the projectile is already flying.
- Fortune's End is not an entangle (doesn't prevent blinks)
- Fate's Eddict can be purged only by Fortune's End which make it very powerfull against right clicker heroes (Slark, Lycan, Void, Phantom Assassin).
- Purifying Flames **can't deny allies**.
- With basic magic resistance (25%) it takes approximately 6 seconds (exaclty 6.14) for the heal of Purifying Flames to compensate the damage done. After the 6 seconds its bonus heal. It's faster the more magic resistance your target has.
- Purifying Flames' heal can be stacked with itself.
- Purifying Flames can be used on summon (Spirit Bear, Warlock's Golem, Storm/Fire Brewlings).
- At the end of False Promise : the doubled heal is applied first, then the damage.
- If the target is invulnerable at the end of False Promise (Eul's,Puck's Phase Shift, Nai'x's Infest, Naga Siren Sleep etc.) the heal/damage wait the invulnerability's end before applying.
- You can use False Promise like Abaddon's Appotic Shield to purge debuff on allies.

### Conclusion

Oracle is a very strong utility support. The spammability of his skills makes him very active in fights and his potential for keeping allies allive and healing them is really strong once you get to master the combos of his skills.

Comment: Just one little thing that is also useful about Fortune's End: The Purge is applied on cast, while the Entangle is applied when the projectile hits, which means you can either cancel the channeling immediately or charge it depending on the situation, the purge is applied at the same time in both cases. Also, a general rule of thumb is that you can apply Fate's Edict onto the enemy right clicker that's fighting your right clicker if most of the damage being done to them is physical, since it also doubles physical damage on the target. Good on targets in Chronosphere, for example.